# how do i use the mysql general log?

Tags: mysql, logging

I notice a very weird problem in my code. I am inserting a value of 128 but in my database it says 127.

I'd like to look at the mysql general/query logs however i dont ever see any log files produce [no matter what i do](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html). I tried -l , -l with an absolute path and --general_log_file. No luck. I also used `mysqladmin flush-logs`. Still nothing

Comment: Is this a "computers start counting at `zero`" situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a signed [`TINYINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) datatype by any chance?

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id TINYINT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (128);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|  127 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: !!! yes! that is the problem. Wow. Why (would mysql let me do that)... ouch.

Whomever reads the title and excepts the answer will be disappointed. Is there an unsigned 1 byte type or do i need to use SMALLINT?

Comment: @acidzombie24: Yes you can use an unsigned 1 byte: `CREATE TABLE my_table (id TINYINT UNSIGNED);`, or if you want to alter your current table: `ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY COLUMN id TINYINT UNSIGNED;`